# Jqgrid - Hide specific fields on edit form depending on row type

Tags: jqgrid

I have "tree grid" table. There are two types of row: parent and children. The parent row contains nested "children" rows.

So, now I want to show different fields on edit form depending on row's type. Table columns are common for all row types.

How can I hide/remove/disable unneeded  fields for inline and modal editing depending on row type?

Please give me a good starting point

Comment: Ок, I figured out: I can use "editable" option. Another way?

Comment: That isn't good enough? You could pass into the rows the type of row it is, (Parent/Child) and then on display of the form hide/disable/readonly the fields that you don't want edited based on what type of row it is.